# Brownian Motion Construction measurable mapping from dyadic rationals to continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion

In chapter 7 of Durrett's Probability theory book [official pdf link here](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf), he presents a construct of Brownian motion.
One step of his argument is unclear to me.

On page 356, he states

> We tidy things up by moving our probability measure to $(C, \mathcal C)$, where $C = \{ \text{continuous}~\omega : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R\}$ and $\mathcal C$ is the $\sigma$-field generated by the coordinate maps $t \to \omega(t)$. To do this, we observe that the map $\psi$ that takes a uniformly continuous point in $\Omega_q$ to its unique continuous extension in $C$ is measurable,...

Note that $\Omega_q$ are functions from the dyadic rationals to the reals.

1. I'm not sure why this map $\psi$ exists (I think it is a real-analysis theorem? Something about the dyadic rationals being dense in the reals we can extend it to continuous functions?)
2. Why is this function measurable (from $(\Omega_q, \mathcal F_q)$ to $(C, \mathcal C))$? It is not clear to me how any set of continuous functions in the sigma-algebra $E \subseteq \mathcal C$, means that $\psi^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal F_q$, where $\mathcal F_q$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $\Omega_q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1, note that a uniformly continous function is Cauchy-continuous and thus can be uniquely extended to the Cauchy completion of its domain; in this case, $\omega$ can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^+=[0,\infty)$. For more details see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-continuous_function).
For 2, you can check as a routine exercise that
$$
\psi^{-1}(\{B_t<a\})=\psi^{-1}(\{\bar{\omega}\in C(\mathbb{R}^+)|\bar{\omega}(t)<a\})
\\=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{m \geq n} \{\omega \in C(\mathbb{Q}_2^+)|\omega(q_m)<a-\frac{1}{k}\}
$$
where $(q_n)$ is any sequence of dyadic rationals converging to $t$. Since sets of the form $\{B_t<a\}$ generate $\mathcal{F}_q$, we have measurability.

Comment: I have a question about the last step. You mentioned that sets of the form $\omega_t < a$ generate $\mathcal {F}_q$ and this concludes the proof. However, there is a gap here. What we have is sets of the form $\{\omega \in C(\mathbb{Q}_2^+ ) | \omega_t < a) \}$. Why is this type of set measurable?

Comment: After some work, I came to conclude that my question above reduces to Theorem 7.1.2. The discussion here assumes Theorem 7.1.2 holds and the theorem guarantees the set of continuous functions is measurable.